# Opensource or libraries for implementing marketplace or app store

Tags: open-source, scalability

I'm going to implement a web-based marketplace for digital contents.
Somehow its features are similar to app store where selling items are apps but my marketplace targets are digital contents.
Before I begin implmenting everything from scratch, I want to make sure that I don't reinvent some wheels. Any recommended tools or personal experience is welcome. Scalability is my main concern for tool adoption.

Comment: did you manage to find something?

Comment: No. Eventually we are implementing an in-house marketplace using Google App Engine. The difficult part is a payment system. We plan to use Paypal's to avoid a lot of headache with financial transactions and credit cards.  https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/payflow-payment-gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been doing some research here and I found a few possible starting points:

- [Open AppStore project](http://open-app-store.org/): where it is not clear what has been so far, but there are no code updates since a year
- [Edukap](https://code.google.com/p/edukapp/) which is in fact a widget store and also hasnt been updated since a year. However the widget delivery/installation component seems to come from [Wookie Apache](http://wookie.apache.org/).

More promising then the ones above, I've found:

- [F-droid](http://f-droid.org/) which is an Android App Store for Open Source Apps. Its development seems quite active and they have a running version of the store and client. However, there doesnt seem to be payment options and I am not sure if you can derive code from them without making it opensource.
- At last, there is the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter) which is perhaps the most promising.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [GigaSpaces XAP](http://www.gigaspaces.com/xap) (Extreme Application Platform).
XAP is a distributed framework to develop scalable, highly available, self healing and transactional systems (and much more).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WSO2 App Manager](http://wso2.com/products/app-manager/) . which provides store  and publisher app management solution for enterprises.